# How do I make certain words inside .val() bold in my jQuery Script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here's a strip of my code:

```
$("#body").val("Dear Supplier,\n\nWe would like to cancel our order of 
[product specifications] made on [date of order submission]. 
Please send us a reply to provide confirmation at earliest convenience. 
\nThank you.\n\nYours sincerely,\n...");
```

Is there any way of making the "[product specifications]" part bold? I tried surrounding it inside the `<b></b>` tags [but that didn't work.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQ0yt.jpg)

EDIT: My #body field is a text area.

Comment: Use `html` instead of `val`

Comment: @JonasW. I got the same output. Didn't work.

Comment: Oh, is it a textarea?

Comment: seems like... why people always forgot the most important things...

Comment: You can't set the value of an input element to contain bold/italic phrases at all

Comment: @JonasW. Yes it's a text area. Sorry people I'm really new to this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there any way of making the "[product specifications]" part bold? I tried surrounding it inside the  tags but that didn't work.

No, it's not possible with `<textarea>`.

You have to resort to a [WYSIWYG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYG) editor.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use a `div` with `contenteditable="true"` instead: $('div#body').html(yourText).

This is if you still want bold phrases in an element but want to maintain the input feature.

Answer (score -1):

The `.val()` allows you to change the **value** of your cibling element. Olr, what you need is to insert code / or replace the existing one with **HTML** tags. SO if you just use the `.html()` function in jQuery it should fit your needs. Here how to do :

```
$("#body").html("<b>D</b>ear Supplier,\n\nWe would like to cancel our order of 
[product specifications] made on [date of order submission]. 
Please send us a reply to provide confirmation at earliest convenience. 
\nThank you.\n\nYours sincerely,\n...");
```

Comment: I did that but it's still the same output. Is it because my #body field is a text area? Sorry I'm really new to this.

Answer (score -1):

$("#body").html("Dear Supplier,\n\nWe would like to cancel our order of \
**[product specifications]** made on [date of order submission]. \
Please send us a reply to provide confirmation at earliest convenience. \
\nThank you.\n\nYours sincerely,\n...");